# Swift 2.0 : NSBundle always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, null, swift2, nsbundle

I'm implementing this git - [NSDate-TimeAgo](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo)

It has swift extension inside. I have dragged and drop the Bundle that the git supply into my app - `NSDateTimeAgo.bundle`

In the extension file im trying to get this file path , but it always return nil
**SWIFT 2.0**

```
func NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(key: String) -> String {

let resourcePath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let path = resourcePath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("NSDateTimeAgo.bundle")
let bundle = NSBundle(URL: path)
print(bundle) -> **nil**

return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "NSDateTimeAgo", bundle: bundle!, comment: "")
}
```

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Does the bundle exist in the app's document folder?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes , I dragged and drop it

Comment: Are we talking about OSX then?

Comment: @trojanfoe IOS app not OSX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle has to be copied into your *resources* folder, not into the top level of your app bundle.

This line is just wrong:

```
let resourcePath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
```

The bundle is not in your documents directory. It's in your app. Look at what the actual code does (in *NSDate+Extension.swift*):

```
func NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(key: String) -> String {

    // LOOK!!!!
    let resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath
    let path = resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("NSDateTimeAgo.bundle")
    let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)

    return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "NSDateTimeAgo", bundle: bundle!, comment: "")
}
```

Basically you should just let it do this. Don't mess with the bundle yourself. Just install *NSDate+Extension.swift* and the bundle, and stop. Don't change the code - all you're doing is breaking it.

Comment: Havent seen you answered! Let me check this real quick

Comment: Matt , im using swift 2.0 - stringByAppendingPathComponent - is available . Any chance you can modify the code above?

Answer (score 0):

In case the accepted haven't worked - found solution -

```
  guard let resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath else {
        return ""
    }

    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:resourcePath).URLByAppendingPathComponent("NSDateTimeAgo.bundle")
    guard let bundle = NSBundle(URL: path) else {
        return ""
    }

    return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "NSDateTimeAgo", bundle: bundle, comment: "")
```